# Register pages programatically in Blazor instead using @page directive using LazyAssemblyLoader

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Currently I load assembly on `OnNavigateAsync` event that contains Razor pages with @page directive like `@page "/extrapage"`, and works fine.

I would like to declare route page programatically, for example, without declaring `@page` and, instead of this, using a `Dictionary<string, string>` where `Key` is the full route of page and the `Value` is the full name of the class that represents the page I would like to register.

I known this seams an strange behavior, but I need to load pages dinamically because I can configure this on data base to add extra pages.

This is an example that represents like I need (App.razor file):

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly"
        AdditionalAssemblies="@LazyLoadedAssemblies"
        OnNavigateAsync="@OnNavigateAsync">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
@code {
    private Dictionary<string, (string AssemblyName, string ClassName)> AssemblyNameAncClassNameByRoute = new Dictionary<string, (string AssemblyName, string ClassName)>();
    private List<Assembly> LazyLoadedAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();

    private async Task OnNavigateAsync(NavigationContext args)
    {
    try
    {
        if (AssemblyNameAncClassNameByRoute.TryGetValue(args.Path, out (string AssemblyName, string ClassName) tuple))
        {
            IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = await AssemblyLoader.LoadAssembliesAsync(new[] { tuple.AssemblyName });
            LazyLoadedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblies);
            
            RegisterRoute(args.Path, Type.GetType(tuple.ClassName));
            
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError("Error: {Message}", ex.Message);
    }

    public void RegisterRoute(string pathRoute, Type pageType)
    {
        //THE CODE I NEED
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not strange, I've done it before.

You don't need to build a new router either.  You can add your custom router to the `NotFound` section of the standard router.

Here's how to do it.

I've used a `<string, Type>` dictionary.

First a barebones Custom Route Service

```cs
public class CustomRouteService
{
    private List<CustomRouteData> _pages = new();

    public IEnumerable<CustomRouteData> Pages => _pages.AsEnumerable();

    public bool TryAddRoute(CustomRouteData data)
    {
        var isComponent = typeof(IComponent).IsAssignableFrom(data.Page);
        var newRoute = !_pages.Any(item => item.Route.Equals(data.Route, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (isComponent && newRoute)
        {
            _pages.Add(data);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool TryAddRoute(string route, string className)
    {
        var page = Type.GetType(className);
        if (page is null)
            return false;

        return this.TryAddRoute(new CustomRouteData(route, page));
    }

    public bool TryGetRoute(string route, out Type? page)
    {
        page = null;
        var data = _pages.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Route.Equals(route, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (data is not null)
            page = data.Page;

        return page != null;
    }
}

public record CustomRouteData(string Route, Type Page);
```

Registered as a Singleton service

Next a `CustomRouteLoader` Razor Component.

```cs
@if (_isRoute)
{
    <RouteView RouteData=_routeData DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
}
else
{
    @this.NotFound
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? NotFound { get; set; }

    [Inject] public NavigationManager NavManager { get; set; } = default!;
    [Inject] public CustomRouteService PageService { get; set; } = default!;

    private Type? _component;
    private bool _isRoute;
    private RouteData? _routeData;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        _routeData = null;
 
        // Get rhe route Uri
        var url = this.NavManager.Uri.Replace(NavManager.BaseUri, "/");
        
        // Try to get the component associated with the route
        PageService.TryGetRoute(url, out _component);

        // Check we have a type and it implements IComponent
        _isRoute = _component is not null && typeof(IComponent).IsAssignableFrom(_component);

        // Create the RouteData
        if (_isRoute &&  _component is not null)
            _routeData = new RouteData(_component, new Dictionary<string, object>());
    }

}
```

Add this to `App`:

```cs
Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CustomRouteLoader>
            <NotFound>
                <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </CustomRouteLoader>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

And a Test page to add and navigate to a custom route

```cs
@page "/"
@inject CustomRouteService customRouteService
@inject NavigationManager navManager

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=this.AddRoute>Add Fred Route</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=this.Navigate>Navigate to Fred</button>

<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=this.AddJonRoute>Add Jon Route</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=this.NavigateJon>Navigate to Jon</button>

@code {

    private void AddRoute()
        => customRouteService.TryAddRoute( new CustomRouteData("/Fred", typeof(Counter) ));

    private void AddJonRoute()
        => customRouteService.TryAddRoute("/Jon", "SO76159043.Pages.FetchData");

    private void Navigate()
        => navManager.NavigateTo("/Fred");

    private void NavigateJon()
        => navManager.NavigateTo("/Jon");
}
```

Comment: I noticed that Singleton class is instanciated every time I load a new page when I click in a link, or if I write the url in browser or even refresh with F5. This is a bad behavior for me. In your example the behavior is the same?

Comment: I tested with <a> tag, <NavLink> element and the method navManager.NavigateTo("path") and the only works is the last one. Can you clarify me this, please?

Comment: [Polite] I showed you a methodology of how, not a full implementation that meets your [unknown] requirements. I'm assuming you are using WASM.  Where do custom routes come from?  Are they entered at runtime?  If so you need a persistence strategy that meets the route lifetime.  Database? LocalStorage?  Are they set up at compile time?  If so add them to the service when it starts.  AppSettings?

Comment: Now I tried with a page Counter of example of Visual studio and I can see that it dosen't call the Program.cs to recreate the singleton (in this way not appears the loading circle).
Also I test to add @page "/Fred" to the Fred.razor file and calling from an anchor link it works fine like Counter. Maybe the page directive do something different than resolving by code in the CustomRouteService?

Thanks and sorry for the 4 messages.

Comment: No problem. Remember, the responder has no context, just the words you [the OP] write in the question.   There's often a lot of guesswork involved!

Comment: You are right. Is difficult explain  in a single message all the context of the application even more so if oneself does not understand what is necessary and what not until after having read the answer.
To finish, do you think it's because of the @page attribute? Do you know if its behavior can be emulated without “reload” the entire client? Do I open a new question to separate it from this one?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to understand.  Ask it as another question with some context information.  See [mre].

Comment: As you sugest me, I added new question to resolve about this related problem.
The question is in the next link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76174017